# how to check if a stored procedure has been called from another stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So here I am using MysqlYog / Phpmyadmin for my database management.
Now I have lots of store procedure written and now I want to delete a store procedure as it don't have any direct use but I can not because I don't know if this procedure is being called from another procedure or not.
So how can i check that.
FYI : 
DB- MYSQL
Scripting Language : Php

Comment: Have you tried to do a `SELECT` on [24.20 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html)?.

Comment: yes i found it .with select on  INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok .I found it with select query

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%procedureName%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbName';
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible for you to get a clearer view of the dependencies out of the information_schema.routines table by using subqueries.  Suppose we have a few procedures, some of which depend on others, like so (tested with MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.2, dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=339d9a248c9b699b06fb746bfe8773dd))

```
create procedure sub1()
begin
  -- do nothing
end;

create procedure sub2()
begin
  -- do nothing
end;

create procedure sub3()
begin
  -- do nothing
end;

create procedure calls_itself()
begin
  call calls_itself();
end;

create procedure depends_on_three()
begin

  call sub1();
  call sub2();
  call sub3();

end;
```

We can get a list of all procedures:

```
select 
  routine_name used_
from information_schema.routines
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' ;
```

This query includes the procedure code, too:

```
select
    routine_name name_
  , routine_definition code_
from information_schema.routines ;
```

We can find instances of procedure names in the (procedure) source code by using MySQL's INSTR().  This function "Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str." (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr).  If no procedure name occurs in the source code, INSTR() will return 0.  The CASE...WHEN..THEN is used for explaining/commenting the query result(s).  Note: call@index refers to the position "in the string".

```
select 
  source.name_ "procedure"
, instr(source.code_, procnames.used_) "call\@index"
, procnames.used_ "subroutine"
, case 
    when instr(source.code_, procnames.used_) is null 
      then 'no procedure code (empty body)'
    when instr(source.code_, procnames.used_) = 0
      then 'no dependency'
    when source.name_ = procnames.used_ 
     and instr(source.code_, procnames.used_) > 0
      then 'recursion' 
    else 
      'dependency!'
  end "comment"
from (
  select 
    routine_name used_
  from information_schema.routines
  where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
) procnames , (
  select
    routine_name name_
  , routine_definition code_
  from information_schema.routines
  where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
) source 
where instr(source.code_, procnames.used_) > 0  -- remove this for full list!
;
```

Output:

```
+------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| procedure        | call@index | subroutine   | comment     |
+------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| calls_itself     |         14 | calls_itself | recursion   |
| depends_on_three |         15 | sub1         | dependency! |
| depends_on_three |         30 | sub2         | dependency! |
| depends_on_three |         45 | sub3         | dependency! |
+------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```